# Conda: syntax of the environment yaml file vs. venv requirements

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda, virtual-environment

I have a venv requirement text file that I used to create a virtual environment for pip.

I want to setup now an environment in conda, based on the requirement file for pip.
However, there are few lines that I don't know how to "port" from pip to conda syntax.
If I take lines like:

```
scipy>=1.4.1
```

and copy it this way into the conda yaml file:

```
dependencies:
    - scipy>=1.4.1
```

they work fine.
But in the requirement files there are lines like:

```
openexr==1.3.2; platform_system == 'Linux'
dataclasses>=0.8; python_version == '3.6'
```

and if I try to copy those in the same way they give an error.

```
CondaValueError: invalid package specification: openexr==1.3.2; platform_system == 'Linux'
```

What's the proper syntax to "translate" those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda will know your platform already, so the first line keeps only the `openexr` specification. For the second one, Conda manages Python, so that the Python version specification can be included explicitly on a separate line. Altogether, something like

```yaml
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - scipy>=1.4.1
  - openexpr=1.3.2
  - dataclasses>=0.8
```

Comment: Great, thanks. That is what I intuitively did, but I couldn't find anywhere documentation to support this intuition.